# Multiplying data with values in a separate worksheet - vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am attempting to create a macro that takes sales data for an unknown number of clients (and products) located in a worksheet "clients" and multiply it by a set of price breaks located in a separate worksheet "products". For example, say client 1 ordered 150 units of product 1. if the price break for less than 500 units is $10.00, i need to find the product of 150 and 10 and display it in the clients worksheet. I have constructed the for loops to loop through the sales data and place it in the correct place, but i run into an issue trying to multiply the sales data by the price break because they are in separate worksheets. with this code i get a "subscript out of range" error. I have researched and tried everything i can think of, but cannot figure out what is "out of range". What am i doing wrong?

```
    Dim anchor As Range, rngGadgets As Range, rngClients As Range, _
    anchorABED As Range, anchorAAED As Range, _

    Dim numGadgets As Integer, numClients As Integer, x As Integer, _
    i as integer, j as integer

    set anchor = range("A4")

    numGadgets = (Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1)
    MsgBox numGadgets
    numClients = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 4)
    MsgBox numClients

    'Amount before extra discount label
    Set anchorABED = anchor.Offset(0, numGadgets + 2)
    For x = 0 To numGadgets - 1
        anchorABED.Offset(0, x).Value = "Gadget " & x + 1
    Next x

    'multiplication loop 
    For j = 0 To numGadgets - 1
      For i = 1 To numClients
        If anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) < 100 Then
            anchorABED.Offset(i, j).Value = anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) * _
            Worksheets("sheet1").anchor.Offset(j + 1, 1)
        ElseIf anchor.Offset(i, j + 1).Value < 500 Then
            anchorABED.Offset(i, j).Value = anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) * _
            Worksheets("sheet1").anchor.Offset(j + 1, 2)
        ElseIf anchor.Offset(i, j + 1).Value < 1000 Then
            anchorABED.Offset(i, j) = anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) * _
            Worksheets("sheet1").anchor.Offset(j + 1, 3)
        ElseIf anchor.Offset(i, j + 1).Value >= 1000 Then
            anchorABED.Offset(i, j).Value = anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) * _
            Worksheets("sheet1").anchor.Offset(j + 1, 4)
        End If
      Next i
    Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

In your multiplication loop you are trying to multiply the value of an offset of *anchor* (a range object set to the active worksheet's A4) against an offset of *anchor* on another worksheet. You cannot arbitrarily reset the parent of *anchor* on the fly like that.

I'm assuming that the two cells to multiply have the same position on each of their respective worksheets. You can use *anchor's* address to reference a cell on the other worksheet that has the same cell address as *anchor*.

```
anchorABED.Offset(i, j - 1).Value = anchor.Offset(i, j + 1) * _
   Worksheets("sheet1").Range(anchor.Address).Offset(j + 1, 1)
```

This is not the best way to do things as a requirement is that the two cells from different worksheets maintain a cell reference synchronization. It would be better to have column and row header information so that a dynamic lookup could be performed against the data matrix on the second worksheet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data in sheet1 is not in the same position on sheet2. Sheet1 simply has a table with rows Product 1,...,product x and columns 0, 100, 500, and 1000. Each cell within the table is a price based on the product and number of units ordered. I tried creating a second anchor, anchor2 and setting it to worksheets("sheet1").range("A4"), but that obviously didn't work either. Is there no way that i can reference those cells in sheet1 without completely remodeling my code? I'm not familiar with dynamic lookup...

Comment: @ahoe - The term dynamic lookup means you simply define the cell to reference each time using information for that gadget to get row and column numbers. As you have no sample data, it is impossible to start making suggestions. It may be clear in your mind but I have no idea what it looks like from here.